# Analyse heap dump with visual vm that contains multiple webapplications

Tags: java, jvisualvm, heap-dump

I got an heap dump of a tomcat server that hosts several web applications.

There are several classes that have instances in each of the applications. When I list all classes contained in the dump I get multiple lines for those classes each showing a different amount of instances. So it seems to that each line shows the amount of instances of said class in one of the web applications.

When I use OQL to count all instances of a class, e.g. select count( heap.instances(myClass) ) I do not get the total amount of all instances of myClass but an amount equal to one of those shown in the before mentioned list.

So it seems to me that for some reason the OQL queries are limited to one web application context, even though the heap dump contains several.

What can I do to access all instances of the heap dump?

Comment: Have you tried Eclipse Memory Analyzer? I use it and visual vm just because they have different capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can at least navigate the desired instances by double clicking on the respective entry in the classes view. But still navigating those with OQL seems impossible.

Using Eclipse Memory Analyzer helps in that way but has other short comings so for me that does not help that much unfortunately.